# Did anyone know the package of name youtube application in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube-api

Can anyone help me where can i found the package name of youtube application in android. Because i will be using the Youtube API in my application and it needs a youtube application first to be able to run. Thant's why i need the package name. Thank you in advance :D

Comment: Sure, it is: com.google.android.youtube . You can tell from the Play Store URL: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube

Comment: Thanks @Thommy i will try it immediately :D

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is `com.google.android.youtube`.

To find out, locate it on the play store and then note the `id` parameter in the URL.

Comment: Correct !! thumbs up

Answer (score 5):

The package name is `com.google.android.youtube`.

Answer (score 3):

Nice Question, Just add package name:

**com.google.android.youtube**

and for more view this tutorial, and i believe that you will get your answer.

http://blog.blundellapps.com/click-item-in-a-listview-to-show-youtube-video/http://blog.blundell-apps.com/click-item-in-a-listview-to-show-youtube-video/

Answer (score 1):

For knowing the package name of any application which is installed in your device, please follow the way.

1. Open android studio
2. Connect your device from android studio
3. Open device file explorer (from where you open the Logcat)
4. Select/click data folder -> app folder

Now you will see the list of applications now you can find the package name of desired application.